# how to select from two table in sql

Tags: php, sql, list

i am creating a voting application and i want to select from the database tables and display the result .1 want to get the candidate name form the first table which i call candidate.sql and then get the amout of votes from the second table called voter.

this is the candidate.sql table

```
  id  | candidate
      1  |**mark**  
      2  |**david** 
      3  |**jeff**
```

voter.sql

```
voter_id |  forr    |user  |candidate_id
    1    |**mark**  |tobe  |  1
    2    |**david** |sandra|  2
    3    |**jeff**  |john  |  3
    4    |**jeff**  |steve |  3
    5    |**david** |linda |  2
    6    |**mark**  |ken   |  1
    7    |**mark**  |jacob |  1
```

My question is how do i join it so it can display like a list. e.g

```
mark 3
david 2
jeff 2
```

or is there a better way.

Comment: You have a bad data structure.  If you have a candidate table with a unique id, you should be using the id in the second table.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT forr,count(*) FROM voter
GROUP BY forr
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: While this does get the results the OP asked for, it does not use both tables

Comment: This answer is correct with the data as provided.  However, the data structure is bad because the candidate id is not being used for the foreign key.

Comment: i have added the id of candidate as a foreign key in the voters table so how do i do it by using the two tables

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.candidate, count(*)
FROM candidate c
JOIN voter v ON v.forr = c.candidate
GROUP BY c.candidate
ORDER BY count(*) DESC, c.candidate ASC
```